# How to pull value from response and compare it with another value using requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making two requests to two different APIs.
How do I pull one value from the response, pull another value from the second response and compare them?
ty very much!

```
import requests

BASE_PATH = "https://example_url.com"
ACCESS_TOKEN = "1111"


def fill_basket():
    basket_data = {
            "article": "13",
            "some_info1": "1"
            "some_info2": "2"
    }
    r = requests.post(f"{BASE_PATH}/api/v5/basket/create/",
                      headers={"X-Access-Token": f"{ACCESS_TOKEN}"},
                      json=basket_data
    )
    assert r.status_code == 200, r.text
    return r.json()["some_id"] #here i tried to catch value from the response 1 
fill_basket()

def check_basket():
    b = requests.post(f"{BASE_PATH}/api/v5/basket/calculate/",
                     headers={"X-Access-Token": f"{ACCESS_TOKEN}"}
    )
    assert b.status_code == 200, b.text
    return b.json()["some_id"] #here i tried to catch value from the response 2
check_basket()


assert r.json()["some_id"] == b.json()["some_id"]
```

Here response check_basket request:

```
{
    "quantity": 1,
    "cost": 10,
    "pricesCurrentCountry": {
        "cost": 10,
        "oldCost": 20,
        "discount": 10
    },
    "productList": [
        {
            "some_id": "39KK8ME6BTEL27",
            "article": "101",
        }
    ]
}
```

here response for fill_basket request:

```
{
    "some_id": "39KK8ME6BTEL27",
    "quantity": 1,
    "paymentMethodId": null,
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where `b` is declared/defined, and let us know exactly what you're struggling with?

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer. i have corrected my code. As far as I understand, the problem is that python doesn't understand variables outside of a function. I need to compare two values from different API response files. Error message: "assert r.json()["some_id"] == b.json()["some_id"]
NameError: name 'r' is not defined"

Comment: I've posted an answer below based on your response. Does it help (I can't *really* test because I don't have the right URL and access tokens)? BTW, in your previous comment, you identified a good problem, so you were quite close to the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comment about "variables outside of a function", this [Real Python article about **scopes**](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) may help you.

Since your functions are returning the values, you can either compare the values directly (approach 2) or make an identifier to refer to them (approach 1).

```py
import requests

BASE_PATH = "https://example_url.com"
ACCESS_TOKEN = "1111"


def fill_basket():
    basket_data = {
        "article": "13",
        "some_info1": "1",  # A missing comma caused a syntax error here
        "some_info2": "2"
    }
    r = requests.post(f"{BASE_PATH}/api/v5/basket/create/",
                      headers={"X-Access-Token": f"{ACCESS_TOKEN}"},
                      json=basket_data
                      )
    assert r.status_code == 200, r.text
    # here i tried to catch value from the response 1
    return r.json()["some_id"]


def check_basket():
    b = requests.post(f"{BASE_PATH}/api/v5/basket/calculate/",
                      headers={"X-Access-Token": f"{ACCESS_TOKEN}"}
                      )
    assert b.status_code == 200, b.text
    # here i tried to catch value from the response 2
    return b.json()["productList"][0]["some_id"]


# Approach 1
# Follow this approach if you need to re-use the data.
x = fill_basket()
y = check_basket()
assert x == y

# Approach 2
# Or if you don't need to re-use the data, do this.
assert fill_basket() == check_basket()
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried Approach 1 and it works! But I have another problem: I got the correct value from the answer (fill_basket) but the wrong value from another answer (check_basket). I've added the check_basket response code into the first post. How can I get "some_id" to compare against fill_basket value?

Comment: Could I please see the `fill_basket` response as well?

Comment: Of course! Man, once again, ty so much! pls refer to main post

Comment: Thanks for the data. It seems to me that you might be slightly unfamiliar with dictionaries in Python (which is what JSON is converted to). As you can see, `"some_id"` is *inside* a list, which itself is *inside* `"productList"`. So, you'll have to index (i.e., access by providing the key of the field) each of them. I've edited this into the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Unfortunately, I am a beginner tester and I only learn the basics of writing autotests. Bless you! =)

Comment: If you have completely understood whatever you need to for now, I'm glad it helped (feel free to ask me further otherwise)! Would you mind marking the answer accepted (if it genuinely is a good answer according to you)?

Comment: BTW, this topic (dictionaries) applies to Python more broadly than just in testing. If you want to read up on it, here's a section of the [official documentation on data structures](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html), although you might find this [Real Python article](https://realpython.com/python-data-structures/) more friendly.

Comment: I tried to mark your answer as correct, but I get this message
Thanks for the feedback! "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."
Sorry I can't make a bigger contribution =(

Comment: No problem @Malekulo :) If you want to go ahead: you're trying to upvote instead of [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), so use the tick mark instead of the arrow. Having said so, please don't be pressured for that here.

Comment: Looks like i did it =)